# Access a UITextField in another UIViewControllers view

Tags: objective-c, xcode

This is how I use a XIB view controllers view as a subview in the MainViewController:

```
UIViewController *nameController = [[NameSubViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NameSubViewController" bundle:nil];
nameSubView = [nameController view];
[self.view addSubview:nameSubView];
```

The `nameController view` contains a `UITextField` property. Can I somehow access this property from MainViewController?

EDIT:

If I create a property for the textField in the View Controller too, I'm still not able to get it in MainViewController. Think it's because of the UIView subclassed causing problems?

NameSubViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface NameSubViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;

@end
```

NameSubView.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface NameSubView : UIView

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;

- (IBAction)textFieldReturn:(id)sender;

@end
```

Connections in IB for NameSubViewController:

[Connections, NameSubViewController](http://www.flickr.com/photos/80427098@N07/7886810298/in/photostream)

Connections in IB for NameSubView:

[Connections, NameSubView](http://www.flickr.com/photos/80427098@N07/7886810190/in/photostream)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you create an outlet for the textfield in your nameController? Do that, and then you can retrieve the value using

```
nameController.textField.text
```

In the nib file, click on the file's owner icon (on the left of the nib), and set it's class to your UIView's subclass using the inspector on the right.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you adding view from Controller A in Controller  B. Isn't it better that you create a view by only using its xib file and add that view to your controllers view.
For accessing field, you can assign a tag to your textfield, and where ever in your code you need it, call
    self.view viewWithTag:<#(NSInteger)#>  method.